# jquery callback on custom function

Tags: jquery, callback

The callback on my custom function is not working. Please would anyone help me ?

```
<html>
<body>
<script src='jquery-1.8.2.js'></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e){
  function cb(){
    alert('animation finish');
  }
  $('button').bind({
    'click':function(e,cb){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('div').animate({'height':200,'width':200},1000);
        cb();
     }
  })
})
</script>
<style>
div{
  height:5px;width:5px;background-color:yellow;
}
</style>

<button>click me</button>
<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**edited:**
I cannot do the `.animate(...,1000,function(){...})`
I used the line

```
$('div').animate({'height':200,'width':200},1000);
```

just to represent some other functions in execution -- it is relative complicated, with more conditions, and different animations called depending upon various parameters.

Basically, after all those animations are over, I want a end function `cb()` to execute; which is where I am having the problem.

Maybe something like this would be appropriate :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e){
  var status=0;
  var tmp1=2;tmp2=7;
  function cb(){
    alert('animation finish');
    console.log(status);
  }

  function do_func1(){
     status = tmp1+tmp2;
     $('#ele1').animate({'height':200,'width':200},1000);
  }
  function do_func2(){
     status = tmp1*tmp2;
     $('#ele2').animate({'height':300,'width':300},2000);
  }
  function do_func3(){
     status = tmp1+tmp1;
     $('#ele3').animate({'height':400,'width':400},500);
  }

  function func1(){
     if('a'=='b'){
         do_func1();
     }else if('a'=='c'){
         do_func2();
     }else{
         do_func3();
     }
  }

  $('button').on({
    'click':function(e,cb){
        e.preventDefault();
        func1();
        cb();
     }
  })
})
</script>
```

Comment: Please explain the problem.

Comment: I think .bind() is deprecated since 1.7.you should use .on() instead.

Comment: @raminomrani  Thanks. corrected it. But the main problem remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do somthing like this

```
  <script>

    function cb(){
        alert('animation finish');
    }

    //-----------------------
    $(function()
      {
        $('button').on('click',function(e)
          {
              e.preventDefault();
              var steps=0;
              var totalSteps=5;    // for example

              var checking=setInterval(function()
                                       {
                                         if(steps===totalSteps)
                                         {
                                           cb();
                                           clearInterval(checking);
                                         }
                                       },30);

            $('div').animate({'height':200,'width':200},1000, function(){steps++;});
            $('div').animate({...  another animation  },1000, function(){steps++;});
            ...
            $('div').animate({...  another animation  },1000, function(){steps++;});


         })  // ..on
    }) // ready function
 </script>
```

you can also change the `step++` to anything else you want, and then write a proper condition inside the checking function in order to act upon it...

Comment: Thanks. I get the idea. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
  $('button').bind({
    'click': function (e) {
        $('div').animate({
            'height': 200,
            'width': 200
        }, 1000, function () {
            cb()
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    }
  })
})

function cb() {
alert('animation finish');
}
```

eg: http://jsfiddle.net/xP25Q/2/

Comment: I cannot do the `.animate(...,1000,function(){...})` . I used the line `$('div').animate({'height':200,'width':200},1000);` to represent some other functions in execution; it is relative complicated, with more conditions, and different animations called depending upon various parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the event provided callback function not your previously defined one in your click event handler.

If you want to call your method, you can either rename the parameter in the event handler or rename your function and change the method call.

Comment: Would please provide me an example ? I'm not sure I understand.